# How does the mapping between android resources and resources ID work?

Tags: android, android-resources

It is magical for Android to locate the proper resource just through the ***R.id.XXX***.

AFAIK, the resources are compiled to binary format, so how does this mapping logic work under the hood?

**Maybe** it works like this:

For e.g., in the **layout1.xml**, we got:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1" >
```

and AAPT will generate this in the R.java:

```
public static final int button1=0x7f05000b;
```

When the ***.apk** is genrated, the **@+id/button1** with be substituded with "0x7f05000b".

Thus, when we call:

```
findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

we are essentially still do the search based on the ID, though the ID is a number like 0x7f05000b.

Thanks!

### ADD

**What I really want to know, is how the resource id integer is parsed into the resource content? In other words, how does the Android runtime locate the resource content with resource id as the sole clue?**

For example, how is a drawable picture found with a resource id? Or how is a string value is found with a resource id?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

At build time, the aapt tool collects all of the resources you have defined (though separate files or explicit definitions in  files) and assigns resource IDs to them.

A resource ID is a 32 bit number of the form: PPTTNNNN.  PP is the package the resource is for; TT is the type of the resource; NNNN is the name of the resource in that type.  For applications resources, PP is always 0x7f.

The TT and NNNN values are assigned by aapt arbitrarily -- basically for each new type the next available number is assigned and used (starting with 1); likewise for each new name in a type, the next available number is assigned and used (starting with 1).

So if we have these resource files handled by aapt in this order:

```
layout/main.xml
drawable/icon.xml
layout/listitem.xml
```

The first type we see is "layout" so that is given TT == 1.  The first name under that type is "main" so that is given NNNN == 1.  The final resource ID is 0x7f010001.

Next we see "drawable" so that is given TT == 2.  The first name for that type is "icon" so that gets NNNN == 1.  The final resource ID is 0x7f020001.

Last we see another "layout" which has TT == 1 as before.  This has a new name "listitem" so that gets the next value NNNN == 2.  The final resource ID is 0x7f010002.

Note that aapt by default makes no attempt to keep these identifiers the same between builds.  Each time the resources change, they can all get new identifiers.  Each time they are built, a new R.java is created with the current identifiers so your code gets the correct values.  Because of this, you must never persist resource identifiers anywhere where they can be used across different builds of your app.

Once the resources are compiled and identifiers assigned, aapt generates the R.java file for your source code and a binary file called "resources.arsc" that contains all of the resource names, identifiers, and values (for resources that come from separate file, their value is the path to that file in the .apk), in a format that can easily mmapped and parsed on the device at runtime.

You can get a summary of the resources.arsc file in an apk with the command "aapt dump resources <path-to-apk>".

The format of the binary resource table is documented in the header file for the resource data structures here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h

The full implementation for reading the resource table on the device is here:

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp

Comment: BTW, are these details documented somewhere?

Comment: The implementation details aren't documented besides the structure definitions I link to here.

Comment: BTW, IMHO, "RTFSC" is wrong. The source is an interpretation of the spec and can change. If there's no spec, then the behavior is officially undefined. Reading the source only tells you what the author thought the spec meant at the time they wrote it. It tells you what happens *now*, but not what *will* happen later. Still Dianne's excellent explanation will probably give you what you need to know and remain relevant for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @edward-falk: I think RTFSC is correct here as the question in first place is about under-the-hood stuff (which is never officially spec'd), not API. The internal spec is the SC :)

Comment: Are references to strings and other values in XML resolved at build or runtime?  <TextView text="@string/foo" />?

Comment: Thank you so much for this @hackbod ! I'm really happy that I got to use this in LeakCanary to shove a map of id resource ids to their corresponding names.

https://github.com/square/leakcanary/pull/1663

Comment: If you want to persist a sort of resource identifier between builds what would be a good way? I mean, some sort of bespoke mapping mechanism I guess but how?

Answer (score 8):

If you are interested in the internal implementation (device side)  have a look at loadDrawable() in [Resources.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java). Refer to hackbod's excellent answer for information about [extracting data from the](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/androidfw/ResourceTypes.cpp) [resource table](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/include/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h)

To know how layouts are translated into View's from resource ID's check out [LayoutInfater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).java

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand, aapt will auto-generate unique IDs for each of your resources and store them in a look-up table. This look-up table is persisted as the "resources.arsc" file located in "bin/resources.ap_" (this is just a ZIP file, so feel free to open using your favorite ZIP viewer). The look-up table is also persisted as R.java, which as you know allows you to reference your resources in Java.

If you want more information on the ARSC file, I would suggest Googling it, or reviewing the code of http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/.

-Dan

Comment: Thanks for the important clue. I will take a search. I will mark your answer if no better one appears. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One final note: for the longest time, I didn't use relative layouts because many items need to reference items further down in the xml file, and I didn't know how to reference an **@id/foo** that hadn't been defined yet.

```
<!-- doesn't work -->
<TextView android:layout_above="@id/foo">above</textview>
<TextView android:id="@+id/foo">below</textview>
```

Then one day I realized (duh) that you can **define** an id in the reference; it doesn't have to be in the element that bears the id:

```
<!-- works -->
<TextView android:layout_above="@+id/foo">above</textview>
<TextView android:id="@id/foo">below</textview>
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic is in the Eclipse plug-in and the R.java file it autogenerates in an app's "gen" folder. If you peek into this file, you'll see static mappings for every XXX in R.xx.XXX where xx can be anim, array, color, and every other resource type.