# Is the integer parameter passed to setContentView(int) a pointer?

Tags: android

I've looked in the generated R file, and the values in there definitely look like memory addresses, but is that the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is a generated number that references the output of `aapt`.

Comment: Kind of timely: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work for a couple of longer discussions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not memory addresses. Its just a specially encoded IDs.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not memory address. They are simply auto generated values that are reference by the compiler.