# Android Data paths

Tags: android, path

I am trying to make a file containing the folder res/raw so I can use `listFiles()` so I can index all the files in that folder... I tried using

```
File folderDirectory = new File("/data/data/com.soundboard/res/raw/");
file[] soundFiles = soundDirectoory.listFiles();
```

ListFiles returns null, I think, unless I am reading my debugging info wrong (the soundFiles path is null)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: uhhh so How would I tell File (java.io) where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `cd /data/data/com.soundboard` in adb shell to find there is no `res/raw` there.

Usually, `res/raw` in .apk should be static, so you could unzip .apk simply and find out what are in `res/raw`.

Answer (score 0):

`res/raw` can not be opened as a File and used as a directory. There is no way to index the files in that folder.

EDIT: when you build your APK the contents of the `res/raw` directory are compiled into an efficient format. See [How does the mapping between android resources and resources ID work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work) for more detail. The best you might be able to do is use reflection on your packages `R.raw` class and list all its fields: I've never seen this done, so whether it will actually work is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using /assets and the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html). It behaves exactly like a file system, so you can use list. The /assets and /res/raw serve much the same purpose, with the one big exception is that /assets can be accessed as a file system.

Otherwise as Femi mentioned, you could use reflection and [get the fields](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) for com.soundboard.R.raw. You could then iterate over those and generate file descriptors for each file there.