# What is the use of the res/values/public.xml file on Android?

Tags: android, android-resources

I've searched on Google, but couldn't find any relevant results.

I also checked **the official Android docs** and [**this page**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html) (for all the available resources) was all I could find. The **relevant links** (to the **`res/values/`** directory) I found on this page were:

- [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)
- [style resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)
- [more resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)

These pages don't tell anything about the **`res/values/public.xml`** file.
Here is an **example** I found for [**this  type of file**](http://pastebin.com/LM2xkRGp).

### Small snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <public type="attr" name="commentTextColor" id="0xAA010007" />
    <public type="drawable" name="add_icon_bl" id="0xAA020000" />
    <public type="layout" name="act_date_picker" id="0xAA030001" />
    <public type="anim" name="activity_slide_from_bottom" id="0xAA040000" />
    <public type="xml" name="pref_menu" id="0xAA050000" />
    <public type="raw" name="alert_bell_animation_bl" id="0xAA060000" />
    <public type="array" name="taskRepeat" id="0xAA070000" />
    <public type="color" name="theme_main_color_bl" id="0xAA080000" />
    <public type="string" name="no_internet" id="0xAA0a0001" />
    <public type="id" name="page1" id="0xAA0d0015" />
</resources>
```

As you can see from the **`type`** attribute, it contains pretty much **all the standard resource types** that you normally put in **separate directories** under the **`res`** directory...

---

**Why would one want to misuse the directories that Android provides and use a single file to store all the values in? Can someone give more information about this?**

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The file **res/values/public.xml** is used to assign fixed resource IDs to Android resources.

Consider these set of string resources in **res/values/strings.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">String 1</string>
    <string name="string3">String 3</string>
</resources>
```

The Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) might assign the following resource IDs for these resources when the app is compiled:

```
public final class R {
    // ...
    public static final class string {
        public static final int string1=0x7f040000;
        public static final int string3=0x7f040001;
    }
}
```

Now, change the set of string resources to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="string1">String 1</string>
    <string name="string2">String 2</string>
    <string name="string3">String 3</string>
</resources>
```

and you'll notice that the resource ID for `@string/string3` has changed:

```
public final class R {
    // ...
    public static final class string {
        public static final int string1=0x7f040000;
        public static final int string2=0x7f040001;
        public static final int string3=0x7f040002; // New ID! Was 0x7f040001
    }
}
```

To prevent this, you can use **res/values/public.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <public type="string" name="string3" id="0x7f040001" />
</resources>
```

which will result in the resource IDs being assigned as follows:

```
public final class R {
    // ...
    public static final class string {
        public static final int string1=0x7f040000;
        public static final int string2=0x7f040002;
        public static final int string3=0x7f040001; // Resource ID from public.xml
    }
}
```

Applications rarely have any use for **res/values/public.xml** since the resource IDs assigned to resources does not matter. When they change, the entire application is rebuilt anyway so any references in Java code to resources by resource ID will be updated.

The most significant user of **res/values/public.xml** is the Android platform itself. Applications built against old versions of Android assumes that certain resource have a certain resource ID. For example, the Android resource [`@android:style/Theme`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Theme) must always have the resource ID 0x01030005 for the platform to be backwards compatible with apps built against old versions of the platform.

If you are curious about more details on how resource IDs are assigned, please refer to this answer: [How does the mapping between android resources and resources ID work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work/6646113#6646113)

Comment: Is it possible to define public resource IDs in my own project, I tried but failed? @IgorPopov

Comment: It was possible to use public.xml in own projects to fix resource ids until 2015. In 2015 Google has broken (as usual) this functionality in gradle and refused to fix it. Here is the link to corresponding issue: [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182046)

Answer (score 13):

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources

public.xml is useful for library projects in general. If you include a public.xml, it's assumed that the rest of your resources are meant to be private.

Although private resources will still be usable by other projects, the linter will warn about using them, and they won't be included in AndroidStudio's autocompletion.

Here's a gist for autogenerating public.xml
https://gist.github.com/HannahMitt/99922d4183bdb03356fd339413ba6303

Answer (score 3):

Is it not a file just for the use authors of the OS code to define a mapping between symbolic names and system resource ids?

You'll find it in your SDK at YOUR_SDK_LOCATION\platforms\android-??\data\res\values.

It's headed

> This file defines the base public resources exported by the platform,
>   which must always exist

and has the caveat:

> IMPORTANT NOTE FOR ANYONE MODIFYING THIS FILE READ THIS BEFORE YOU
>   MAKE ANY CHANGES
>
> This file defines the binary compatibility for resources.  As such,
>   you must be very careful when making changes here, or you will
>   completely break backwards compatibility with old applications

It has entries such as

```
<public type="attr" name="smallScreens" id="0x01010284" />
<public type="attr" name="normalScreens" id="0x01010285" />
<public type="attr" name="largeScreens" id="0x01010286" />
```

in it - all system resurce ids, so anyone changing entries will break their code, insomuch as it won't run on a standard device.

Comment: I didn't know about the file being part of the Android SDK... Anyway, the example I found doesn't change existing values, it just creates other, custom ones... so I don't think the restriction you posted applies in this case.

Comment: I guess that it must be for the use of people who want to develop custom OS ROMs. If you added a new system resource name/id, then you could compile the app code and ROM code to make use of it. The app would only run on your custom ROM phone though.

Comment: No, I found this in a normal app, not in a custom ROM.