# Does the getID() always return a constant value?

Tags: android, constants

For my Android project, I am using the `getID()` method to retrieve the numeric value for a View and store this value in my database.  I am banking that this `getID()` method for a particular View will always return the same constant value over multiple executions in a production environment and over subsequent application changes over years.  Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Aren't the IDs generated by the tools? Unless you can explicitly set an ID's *value* I would not count on relying on consistent behavior of the numeric value itself.

Comment: I don't recommend using `if(view.getId() == 0x07010001)` since that may change, but using `if(view.getId() == R.id.view)` is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`View#getId()` is the value of `R.id.xyz` you define in your layout xml files. They don't change until you recompile your app since that changes the generated R.java file (not necessarily changing the numeric id value though).

> over multiple executions in a production environment

yes, if the app is not updated

> and over subsequent application changes over years

maybe, but I would not assume that. There is maybe a way to setup your tools to generate predetermined fix id values since Android itself has stable [resource ids](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html) but Idk how that is done.

Comment: Thanks zapl.  I didn't have a good feeling relying on getID() over future application and Android SDK changes.  I'm glad I asked now.

Comment: Sam, Yes, I am comfortable with "if(view.getId() == R.id.view)", but I am actually storing R.id.View (which returns 0x07010001) in my database for future reference and I think I'm asking for trouble. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: For ids to be constant across builds you have to declare ids in public.xml(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android)

Comment: @user1005585 I found this comment by change, please read [Markdown: Comment Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#comment-formatting) for some tips and tricks in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nandeesh, very interesting.  I like it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sam Thanks. I'll do that from now on.