# Is it safe for me to save resource id as user preference

Tags: android

Currently, I define several theme in my app

- `R.style.Theme_MyApp_Light`
- `R.style.Theme_MyApp_Dark`

User has the option to save his selected theme in preference.

I was wondering, is it safe for me to save these generated Id into preference? Possible in my next app release, **aapt** generates different resource id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every build the generated resource id will be different. But you can generate fixed resource ids by using [public.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android) . Then you can safely store resource ids in preference.

Comment: OK. I never heard of public.xml. Now I know :)

Comment: This is no longer true. The public.xml file no longer works because it was removed.