# How to add id to public.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-xml

In my project, I needed to set always-constant IDs to Views. I mean IDs that are constant between different app builds. After some investigation I found that it can be achieved by using `values/public.xml` and any id declared in that file would not change on future builds. Now the problem is that I can't define an id of a view in some layout file.
This is my layout.xml containing an ImageView with an Id which should be added to public.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/menu_item_selector" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/index_row_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_small" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/index_row_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/index_row_search" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/index_row_caption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/index_row_icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/index_row_search"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and this is public.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
        <public type="string" name="no_internet" id="0xAA0a0001" />
        <public type="id" name="index_row_search" id="0xAA0b0015" />
</resources>
```

eclipse shows an error on the line where I have added id of "index_row_search" and says:

`error: Public symbol id/index_row_search declared here is not defined!`

but as you can see in above layout file, I have an ImageView with that id. It's wondering that the string id definition one line above has no error!

So, how should I define Id of a View in public.xml?

Comment: "I needed to set always-constant IDs to Views. I mean IDs that are constant between different app builds" -- why?

Comment: Agreed with CommonsWare on that. Also, have you cleaned/rebuilt your project?

Comment: @CommonsWare because I want later be able to manipulate some layouts, without recompiling, and you know, rebuilding resources by aapt may change some id's.

Comment: @CommonsWare think of this, as a project that designer likes to change some layouts a bit without any need to recompile and having source. So I should provide him a classes.dex file that uses always-constant id's which won't change on rebuilding.

Comment: @Eric my question is linked to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android

Comment: ...okay, that's fine. I asked if you had cleaned and rebuilt your project, though.

Comment: @Eric yes, I have cleaned and rebuild many times, but no success. I'm wondering because string definition works but id does not.

Comment: Is it perhaps because the `ImageView`'s ID is `@+id/index_row_search`? Shouldn't it be `@id/index_row_search`?

Comment: Is the string no_internet present in strings.xml?

Comment: @Eric No, I tested both.

Comment: @nandeesh Yes, the string is defined and has no problem, but id has problem however it is defined, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a new xml ids.xml in values with all the id values which are to be constant.

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="index_row_search" />
</resources>
```

I think its better if you copy the resource ids to public.xml from the R.java, the first time to avoid errors like **entry index is larger than available symbols** and also to keep the [type of resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/1109425) to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks man, you are my hero :) It seems to work properly. I was completely ignorant of ids.xml which you pointed to. first I declared <item type="id" name="index_row_search" /> in ids.xml and then <public type="id" name="index_row_search" id="0x7f060000" /> in public.xml and it goes without error and seems the id would stay constant between builds. Hooray!

Comment: why am i getting different ID values by using this way @yrajabi