# Setting getIDs permanently

Tags: android

For business reasons, I have to capture the ID's of Views in my application.  Since I don't want the ids to change over multiple deployments, I have created ids.xml and public.xml as described here [How to add id to public.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334857/how-to-add-id-to-public-xml?lq=1)

I have about 200 ids on the app, and I need to capture only about 150 of those.  My question is, should I refer to all 200 ids in my ids.xml and public.xml OR just refer to the ones I need (the 150) would be good enough?
Thank you.

Comment: "For business reasons, I have to capture the ID's of Views in my application" -- that sounds very strange. After all, you do not create all the views yourself (except in very trivial apps) and therefore do not have control over their IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These IDs are dynamic, and therefor you cannot capture them reliably (they most likely will change with each compile).

Maybe you can create custom attributes to use instead (like here: http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/)

Bottom line, it is a bad practice to capture the ids.

I also think there is a 'Tag' attribute you can use in layout files, so you may want to try that as well.

Comment: Thank you. I read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android as well and I went with getID(). I think I'll set tags and use getTag() instead.  Thanks again