# Error in public.xml string declared here is not defined

Tags: java, android, xml, recompile

> F:apkmanager\3-Out\apk.apk\res\values\public.xml:1359: error: Public symbol string/showSlip declared here is not defined.
>
> Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec command:

```
<public type="string" name="showSlip" id="0x7f0c00d0" />
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334857/how-to-add-id-to-public-xml

Answer (score 0):

decompile again to a different folder and copy res/values/public.xml over!