# android studio Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android

I decompiled an app using an online tool (www.decompileandroid.com) then, after I downloaded the zipped source code (assets + java code), I extracted it in a folder and finally I imported the folder in android studio (File>New>Import Project).
Then, without editing any file, I tried to run the project but I got this error:

`Error: Found item ###/ITEM-NAME more than one time`

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > C:\Users\Fabrizio\AndroidStudioProjects\com.hwlogos.ytstars\app\src\main\res\values\public.xml: Error: Found item ###/ITEM.NAME more than one time
```

I searched the web for hours but I can't find any useful answer...

Please  help!

PS: I tried also with other applications but I always get the same error...

**UPDATE:**

Now I tried to decompile a simple app i created with android studio and  when I reimported it in android studio I got the same error.
it seems there are two resources with the same name, one declared as string and the other as id.
Here's a part of my public.xml, which i never wrote when I made my application!!!

```
<public type="string" name="action_settings" id="0x7f070006" />
<public type="id" name="action_settings" id="0x7f09000a" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new xml ids.xml in values with all the id values which are to be constant.

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="index_row_search" />
</resources>
```

I think its better if you copy the resource ids to public.xml from the R.java, the first time to avoid errors like entry index is larger than available symbols and also to keep the [type of resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/1109425) to be consistent.

visit here for more help [How to add id to public.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12337520/5202007)