# AOSP building error: symbol not defined

Tags: android-source, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm trying to build the [cornerstone](https://github.com/Onskreen/cornerstone) based on AOSP 4.3_r2.2. I got a lot of errors during the building like these:

```
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:244: error: Symbol 'config_bluetooth_adapter_quick_switch' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1558: error: Symbol 'config_enableDreams' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:919: error: Symbol 'ic_suggestions_add' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:920: error: Symbol 'ic_suggestions_delete' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1244: error: Symbol 'backspace' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1250: error: Symbol 'carrier' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:130: error: Symbol 'dangerous_perms_list' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1253: error: Symbol 'emergencyCallButton' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1254: error: Symbol 'faceLockAreaView' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1256: error: Symbol 'forgotPatternButton' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1258: error: Symbol 'headerText' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1260: error: Symbol 'instructions' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:1263: error: Symbol 'lockPattern' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml:131: error: Symbol 'non_dangerous_perms_list' declared with <java-symbol> not defined
...
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk'
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I searched here and found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334857/how-to-add-id-to-public-xml). So I know this could be missing the symbol definition problem. But when I look at the public.xml, I see they belong to different types like these:

```
<java-symbol type="bool" name="config_bluetooth_sco_off_call" />
<java-symbol type="bool" name="config_enableDreams" />
<java-symbol type="drawable" name="ic_suggestions_add" />
<java-symbol type="drawable" name="ic_suggestions_delete" />
<java-symbol type="id" name="backspace" />
<java-symbol type="id" name="carrier" />
<java-symbol type="id" name="dangerous_perms_list" />
...
```

I also found there's a script file at frameworks/base/core/res/MakeJavaSymbols.sed, it says the command

```
make framework 2>&1 | sed -n -f MakeJavaSymbols.sed | sort -u
```

can be used to generate the missing resources. I searched a lot, all I found  just to run this command, and it'll output the missing parts. But I ran it, nothing happened. So my question is where and how should I add these missing symbols? There are hundreds of them, do I need to add them manually? Did I missed something? Since I'm new in AOSP framework, so please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved the problem, by did these:
1. Removed the symbol definition from public.xml;
2. Replaced android.view.Surface with android.view.SurfaceControl, and WindowManagerService.DEFAULT_DIM_DURATION with WindowAnimator.DEFAULT_DIM_DURATION.

After that, I compile it succeed, and it can be run, although there still have some problems.