# Android Robolectric Library class support. How to have library class R references load from application project

Tags: android, unit-testing, reflection, classloader, robolectric

I'm trying to implement support for Library projects in Robolectric (android unit testing framework). I have the framework loading all resources for the library projects and have tested this to work just fine. The process is pretty simple, from the RobolectricConfig I read in the project.properties and look for android.library.reference.x values in a loop, and recurse through each project.

The tricky part has to do with resolving R references at runtime when doing so from the Library Project codebase. Lets say for example that we have an application with 1 library project like so:

**com.example.app** which depends on library **com.example.lib**

Both projects have resources in them.  Under the com.example.app project we have:

**gen/com.example.app.R**

**gen/com.example.lib.R**

com.example.app.R is a superset of com.example.lib.R as it contains all of com.example.lib.R's definitions and then those that have been added because of its own resources. I originally thought they were identical but I was wrong, they are in fact different. However for R's inner classes ((R.string, R.color, R.attr, etc) the name/values map the same as they corresponding values in com.example.app.R in the app project. The library project's R classes values do not map the same though as the one in the application project.

As a simplification, lets say they look like this:

```
package com.example.app;

public final class R {
      public static final class string {
            public static final int a = 0x7f050001;
            public static final int a = 0x7f050002;
            public static final int c = 0x7f050003;

     }

}

//this file is in the application project
package com.example.lib;

public final class R {
     public static final class string {
            public static final int c = 0x7f050003;

     }
}
```

Then, under the library project there is **gen/com.example.lib.R**:

```
//this file is in the library project
package com.example.lib;

public final class R {
     public static final class string {
            public static final int c = 0x7f040003;
     }
}
```

So what happened is that the library has **c** defined in an string.xml and the project does not. The value for R.string.c in the library's values are not the same as the application's R values (c = 0x7f050003 in app and c = 0x7f040003 in library). I understand that the library doesn't know about the application thus it's own R class can't possibly generate values that are the same, and thus the application class must have its values re-mapped. What I want to know is how could I possibly, at runtime, use the com.example.lib.R values that are defined in the application project as opposed to those defined in the library's com.example.lib.R class?

What fails is that when the Robolectric Test runner is running my test, when it gets into the library project codebase I do a lookup for string **c**, as so:

```
 resources.getString(R.string.c);
```

So what I get when I do the lookup is 0x7f040003 instead of 0x7f050003. It seems most values map exactly 0x10000 higher but that does not always work out so I can't rely on that.

What I don't understand is how come if we have 2 classes with the same package name and the one from the application comes first in the classpath (which I verified at runtime by printing out  System.getProperty("java.class.path") at runtime), why does the library project still use its own **com.example.lib.R** definitions rather than the equivalent version in the application project? They both have the exact same canonical name.

I imagine something in the class loader says that this class (lets call its MyLibraryActivity)
only knows about the com.example.lib.R class that it depends on, and loads that one.  Perhaps the security manager or something makes that decision? I have no idea really. But I would hope that somehow I could change this behavior so that library project resource lookups from within the library project could resolve to the version in the application project (since after all, it is in the class path). Maybe there is a way I can force load this class ahead of time so the system doesn't try to reload it?

I understand that there is no dependency between the library project and the application project and I definitely don't want to add that dependancy, however I'd like the values at runtime to come in from the application's R class instead of the library R class.

Anyone have any idea why this happens and also if there is a way for me to force the application R class to be the one that the application project references?

-- Update --

After some thought, I believe the problem is that the java compiler is inlining these values since they are final static variables and thus there would be no way to fix the problem with class loading changes.

Another idea I had at one point was to load all of the library project's R classes, and map the variables to the application projects variables in the R class. Whenever getValue was called I would somehow (at runtime) analyze the stack to determine who the caller was and which R class was associated with that caller. From there I could determine what the associated ID was from the application project and the lookup would work as expected.

Anyone have an idea if this is possible? I know how to get the stack trace at runtime and could put in some logic to figure out who the caller was, but figuring out which R class is associated with that caller seems complicated, slow, and probably error prone.

-- Update Again --
What about doing something like using http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/ to modify the class file at runtime, substituting the values where appropriate! This would be amazing but probably pretty difficult.

Comment: The version of the R class in the library does NOT have the constant as final to avoid inlining. As for which version is used, this depends on the import only. The class loader or the security manager have nothing to do with it.

Comment: You're right it isn't final in the library's R class. It is final though in the same class for the application though. Why does it matter which import statement is used? The app and lib project both contain the same class (com.example.lib.R), so how does the system pick which one to use at runtime? How can I switch that?

Comment: oh no I thought you were confused with the two R classes in the application project. The R class that's generated in the library project is not packaged with the jar generate by the project. It's only used to compile those classes (the non final bit makes the compiler not inline the values). The R class created in the app project is the one that gets packaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android library project doesn't run on itself, it is always compiled indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application and building that application.

The only purpose of R.java generated in library project's gen folder is to accomplish the library project itself, so that IDE won't pop any compile error when seeing code like `resources.getString(R.string.c);` in the library project. The library project's R.java is more like a temp file, it will never get pushed into application project's apk file.

Think the library project as two parts, the pure Java source (my-lib/src/) and Android resources (my-lib/res/). The pure Java source is compiled and end up as my-lib/bin/my-lib.jar (note that there is no R.class file in this so-called temporary jar), when you reference the library project in the application project, it does add my-lib.jar as a dependency in the application project (in Eclipse Package Explorer, check out `my-app -> Android Dependencies -> my-lib.jar`). The Android resources are globally merged and compiled later when ADT think it is time  to do so, usually when application project is built for run/debug.

The R java files that  get compiled and packed into the final apk are those under application project's gen folder, in the apk file,  they are injected under the corresponding package, like so:

```
com/
  example/
    lib/
      R       <- com.example.lib.R.java
      ... ... <- package/class from my-lib.jar
    app/
      R       <- com.example.app.R.java
      ... ... <- package/class from application project
```

The inconsistent R value generated between library and application project is not a problem, this is guaranteed by the SDK design. For you Robolectric pull request, always use R files from application project accordingly.

Most of info I mentioned can be found in [Library Projects & Development considerations section from official dev guide](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects).

Comment: I understand that I should use the values from the R files that exist in my project. The problem is that there is code in my library project that makes references to the R values (R.string.c) and when robolectric runs, the value is the one defined in the library project. I made several attempts to map values from library project to main project but this fails when you have multiple library projects (whcih some of my projects do), so I gave up on that. Thus, I need to somehow force the classloader to load, and use, the R class from my application project..

Comment: Also note that if I write the the same exact code, getString(R.string.c) in my application code, it will return the value I want, but from the library code that is called right after that, with the same exact line, will return the value from the library project's R class file.. I'm not sure why the class loader does this though.

Comment: Where do you use and write Robolectric test class, in application project or library project? Library project compilation is only constrained by Android SDK, both Maven and Robolectric doesn't care it. If you use and run Robolectric in library project, it would use the value from library project's R file. I usually presume this constraint myself and don't use Robolectric in Library project.

Comment: What you do is you create a new project and you add Robolectric junit test runner, and you add your own project/library project as dependancies. I have it ordered such that my project is higher than my library project but that didn't fix the order that com.example.lib.R was resolved. It seems that the com.example.lib.R is loaded twice, once from application and once from library.

Comment: I followed these instructions to get started: http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html
I had to additionally add my library project as a dependancy. I have the library project in eclipse as its own project and I used that.

Comment: _It seems that the com.example.lib.R is loaded twice, once from application and once from library._ If this is true, it is very likely a bug in Robolectric, the library's R should be explicitly excluded from Robolectric classloader when Robolectric is started from application project, even though the library project support in current Robolectric release is pretty blank.

Comment: yeah which is the problem i'm trying to solve! Can't figure out how to prevent it from being loaded a second time and simply use the one already existing. P.S. if you're interested it's actually really easy to get setup to develop for robolectric, simply checkout the repo, run maven setup, import the pom.xml with eclipse (need the maven plugin to do so).. Might be a few other things but it's pretty simple.

Comment: _I had to additionally add my library project as a dependancy._ Can you explain what you did for this? Are you adding the library project  to application project's classpath (Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add) besides referencing the library project (Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add), if yes, this could be the cause of R file loaded twice.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20910/discussion-between-matt-wolfe-and-yorkw)

Comment: Thanks for the help. sorry I would have given you the bounty if I had it working before the deadline.. Someone else upvoted the other answer and so it ended up getting half the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Since Library project's resources are always included in the Application project, you could always assign fixed values to resources in Library project.

That could solve your problem.
You can declare public.xml to assign fixed values so that the same values are imported to Application project too.

Depending upon the number of resources in your Library this might be tedious.

You need to create public.xml in res/values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <public type="string" name="c" id="0x7f050003" />
</resources>
```

For more details check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357813/1109425)

Comment: The original question is not well explained, the problem is due to abnormal projects creation and setup following [this tutorial](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/eclipse-quick-start.html). Once the projects are setup properly, no extra action needed to make it work. More in [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20910/discussion-between-matt-wolfe-and-yorkw).