# how to change number picker style in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-holo-everywhere

I want to use the NumberPicker component-widget but Instead in the default Holo theme I need to replace the blue color with orange since that is the default color in my styling.
How can I replace the blue color and the color of the numbers,and keep all of the functionality of the component?
[image: the default number picker in Holo]
thanks

Comment: Why Google doesn't allow styling NumberPicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make copy of library/res/drawable-*/numberpicker_selection_divider.9.png and name then, for example, custom_np_sd.9.png.

Override default NumberPicker style via activity theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Holo.Theme">
  <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/CustomNPStyle</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomNPStyle" parent="@style/Holo.NumberPicker">
  <item name="selectionDivider">@drawable/custom_np_sd</item>
</style>
```

And apply @style/AppTheme as activity theme.

Comment: where can I find the library folder in order to copy the style

Comment: Not working

Error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.Holo.NumberPicker'. 

 Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:selectionDivider'.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. No resources found. How to use it?

Answer (score 25):

Unfortunately, you can't style it. The styles and styling attributes for `NumberPicker` are not present in the public API, therefore you can't set them and change the default look. You can only select between light and dark theme.

As a solution I would suggest to use [android-numberpicker](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker) library instead. The library is basically a port of NumberPicker extracted from Android source codes. But it's better than that, it also backports `NumberPicker` to Android 2.x. The library can be easily styled.

To style the divider adjust `NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker` style and its `selectionDivider` and `selectionDividerHeight` attributes. 
To style the text adjust `NPWidget.Holo.EditText.NumberPickerInputText` style.

Comment: but by using the library you suggested the scroll functionality of the component is lost, I would really like to keep this functionality

Comment: The library version can scroll too. There's no problem with that.

Comment: No matter what style I picked, I *always* got black text.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Old comment, I know. You need to override `android:textColorPrimary` in your base theme. This can _possibly_ affect other TextViews' text color (if one is not set explicitly). But, this behavior can be contained on the `Activity` level.

Comment: What is the use of  this library if this too can't style the text for itself? I cannot override `android:textColorPrimary`, as I've already done so differently,

Comment: Adding that the public attributes are marked by the framework using this [res/values/public.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/public.xml). Also, here is a bit more context about [how it works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 10):

Preview of a customized number picker:

[image]

```
<NumberPicker
  android:id="@+id/np"
  android:layout_width="40dp"
  android:layout_height="40dp"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:background="@drawable/drawablenp"
  android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

Create the background xml in the drawable folder named "drawablenp.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:startColor="#707070"
        android:centerColor="#f8f8f8"
        android:endColor="#707070"
        android:angle="270"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem too. I really want to have nice `NumberPicker` UI. All answer in this question worked but very limited. I almost create my own `RecylerView` to create the `NumberPicker` I want. Apparently I found neat library which is very robust. Here is the link https://github.com/Carbs0126/NumberPickerView

Not trying to answer the question here. Just want to help someone with the same problem as I am.

Answer (score 1):

I face this problem too, I use reflect to change the style

```
public class MyNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {
    public MyNumberPicker(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setNumberPickerDivider();
    }

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        setNumberPickerDivider();
    }

    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        setNumberPickerDivider();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        setNumberPickerDivider();
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        super.addView(child);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, index, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        super.addView(child, params);
        updateView(child);
    }

    public void updateView(View view) {
        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            EditText et = (EditText) view;
            et.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.font_content));
            et.setTextSize(16);
        }
    }

    private void setNumberPickerDivider() {

        try {
            {
                Field field = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(this, ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.horizontal_divider));
            }

            {
                Field field = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDividerHeight");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                field.set(this, 1);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will not work on 28+ API.
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/non-sdk-q?authuser=1