# android TimePicker change divider blue color

Tags: android, colors, timepicker

Standard android TimePicker has blue dividers. I need divider of other color (yellow). How can I achieve this. I tried to specify it in res/values/styles.xml , but no result:

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:divider">@color/program_yellow</item>  
    </style>
```

this is my app style, in manifest file. please help

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change number picker style in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031624/how-to-change-number-picker-style-in-android)

Comment: Almost the same but I couldn't do it. Can you explain in more details what should I do ? When I write style like it is says : No resource found that matches the given name attr 'selectionDivider'...