# Android Failed to find style in current theme

Tags: android, android-theme

in this simple designed Theme, Android could not find `numberPickerStyle` ino that and i get this error:

```
 Failed to find 'numberPickerStyle' style in current theme
```

My theme is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Tsms" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/SampleTheme.Tsms</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SampleTheme.Tsms" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

how to fix and resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you copied your code from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15039754/1048340). `numberPickerStyle` would be an attribute that is defined in your app. The code that you copied from the answer does not work. You would need to define an attribute in XML for the error to go away but that still would do nothing for you.

---

You can't style a `NumberPicker`. `android:numberPickerStyle` is private (see this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78878)).

> Unfortunately, you can't style it. The styles and styling attributes
>   for `NumberPicker` are not present in the public API, therefore you
>   can't set them and change the default look. You can only select
>   between light and dark theme. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032921/1048340)

Comment: hi sir, befor create your topic i'm reading your introducing link, but i can not change my code to that. my theme is custom and it does not `AppTheme`, thats `AppCompat`, how to change define that in my style? can you fix my code?

Comment: You need to remove the `numberPickerStyle` line as it doesn't even do anything.

Comment: OH sir. i need to define that in style.

Comment: You can't unless you add `numberPickerStyle` as a custom attribute in your project. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: thanks sir. this problem is for `simonvt.numberpicker` moddule and he say : `Requires adding a single attribute to your theme` such as: `<style name="SampleTheme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.Light.NumberPicker</item>
</style>
<item name="numberPickerStyle">@style/NPWidget.Holo.NumberPicker</item>`

Comment: Ah, you should have mentioned that in the beginning. Are you sure the library is added properly to your project? Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? It should work fine if the library is added to your project. The attribute is there: https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker/blob/master/library/res/values/themes.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68634/discussion-between-andbee-and-jared-rummler).

Comment: i'm added this library in project and i'm using ADT now. please see this link to review Errors: http://pastebin.com/0dcRg6tH