# Android number picker style

Tags: android, numberpicker

I have the following problem : I want to use Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen for my application parrent theme, but with this theme the number picker looks in the older way (with "+" and "-"), but I want to looks like the new way (with the blue dividers). Is there a way to achieve this? It will be sad (and I will lose a lot of time) to write my own picker only, because of the theme ? I will be glad if someone has simple solution. I google it but I insist to not change the style, because the application was always with this style and it will be strange to change the whole style only for that. 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. I try not to make this theme parent theme and just to copy

```
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

this properties in my theme, but then application is not in full screen i.e. not working properly (like with make Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen parent theme ) .

P.S.2 There is Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen and I thing it should work, but I'm not sure what is the difference between it and Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen. 
I will be glad if someone enlighten me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change number picker style in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031624/how-to-change-number-picker-style-in-android)