# Add a small Numberpicker to my layout

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, numbers

[image: App UI]

Hi,

I have this problem: I need my users to choose a number between 1 and 9, but the NumberPicker (as shown above) looks really ugly and all other alternatives aren't better.  Do you have any alternatives?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: Do you want users to pick a number from those choices or its okay with you using EditText that accepts numbers only from 1 to 9. What language are you using to develop?

Comment: An Edit Text only fills up so much space on the screen, I have tried that already. I'd actually like them to choose a number. I'm using xml.

Comment: May you should say how to you want it to be!

Comment: Basically I want some kind of menu, similar to the NumberPicker, which allows me to let the user choose one number. Perhaps even a ray of numbers and you can drag a pointer to a certain place and select one number. Is this understandable?

Comment: May be you should consider visiting this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031624/how-to-change-number-picker-style-in-android

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was helpful :)

Comment: Okay! and **Happy Coding!**

Answer (score 3):

I used to have the same problem as your. And by default Android Component doesn't provide Horizontal NumberPicker.
So I used this one https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker.
Hope it help in your case too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly compact, but as it is horizontal, it probably fits your layout better:
https://github.com/blazsolar/HorizontalPicker

You have to define an array of strings in `res/values/arrays.xml` for putting the items, like:

```
<array name="color_channel_values">
    <item> "0" </item>
    <item> "1" </item>
    <item> "2" </item>
    <item> "3" </item>
    <item> "4" </item>
    <item> "5" </item>
    <item> "6" </item>
    <item> "7" </item>
    <item> "8" </item>
    <item> "9" </item>
</array>
```

Also, to help visualizing the selection, a selector can be used for `textColor`. Example `res/color/horizontal_picker_selector.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:color="#ffffff" />
<item android:color="888888" />
</selector>
```

If you don't like that one, maybe you'll find something you like at https://android-arsenal.com/tag/142 .