# AndroidManifest.xml use integer ids stored in public.xml for themes

Tags: java, android, android-xml

Here is the rough idea of my files. I inherited a bunch of code that uses the `public.xml` file to map `ids` to `themes`. This code throws the error:

`Error:(40, 24) Integer types not allowed (at 'theme' with value '0x7f09007a')`

However, when I replace the `android:theme="0x7f09007a"` with `android:theme="@style/myCoolTheme` everything works. I need to be able to use these `ids` since so much more of the code I inherited uses them. Am I missing something to make the manifest file use the id mapping in `public.xml?`

**app/src/main/res/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...
    <application
       android:theme="0x7f09007a"
       ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**app/src/main/res/values/public.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
       <public type="style" name="myCoolTheme" id="0x7f09007a" />
       ...
    </resources>
```

**app/src/main/res/values/style.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" 
        ...
    </style>
    <style name="myCoolTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme" />
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android), I believe the use of `@style/myCoolTheme` is correct because you are using the `name="myCoolTheme"` of the `public.xml`.

The only purpose of the `id=""` attribute is to merge that integer value into `R.java`, not be referenced by the other XML files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just renaming the name of the resource in the xml to be the same thing? Is it necessary to have the style be named "myCoolTheme"? If not, this may do the trick.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
       <public type="style" name="0x7f09007a" id="0x7f09007a" />
       ...
    </resources
```

If renaming it isn't a problem, you can just use the following in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:theme="@style/0x7f09007a"a
```