# What the purpose of the file symbols.xml in $ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-NNN/data/res/values/

Tags: android, android-resources

I don't understand what the purpose of the file `symbols.xml` in `$ANDROID_SDK/platforms/android-NNN/data/res/values/`

do we need it ?

Answer (score 1):

Android uses this file to define the symbols used is the OS.
E.g, as described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/symbols.xml), where it defines some ASCII elements.

Comment: do i need it in my app? what the difference with public.xml .

Comment: No, you don`t need it. And it has nothing to do with public.xml. To read about public.xml, you can read this answer :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348614/what-is-the-use-of-the-res-values-public-xml-file-on-android