# How to obtain values within R.Java?

Tags: java, android

I presume this will be a bit of a noob question so please bear with me but i am wondering how the values [Shown In Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/easWy.png) are generated for the different source files within R.Java file as shown? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: R u looking for values ? if yes please dont worry and dont depend on it. It getting generated automatically. 
https://www.javatpoint.com/R-java-file-in-android

Comment: @Sush Oh fair thanks man , Guess this leads to my next question.... so if you look at the attached picture you will see that there is a source called "do_junk_clean" which is used as this                                                             ` android:layout_above="@id/do_junk_clean"></ExpandableListView>`   I was wondering how do i make a different id that says "@id/do_Process_kill"

Comment: Make/assign an androidWidget in your xml file with `android:id="@+id/do_Process_kill"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been mentioned in previous answers, R file is being generated every single time during the application build. Every value must be public and static. This file should be never edited manually.

You can compare this file with some kind of a "manifest" for the app that defines what property name is responsible for what. And in order to navigate to the `R.x.x` value usage - simply click on the property while holding `CTRL`.

Now to the more "in-depth" answer. To my mind here is the most accurate explanation of the generation process, if that's what you were looking for: ['Deep' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/3649567).

Good luck!

Comment: Cheers mate! Thank you for the help :D

Comment: @ThomasMortell you're always welcome :)