# clans FAB Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android, exception, floating-action-button

I posted my first app and rarely it crashes. I get `Resources$NotFoundException` on `com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu.setMenuButtonColorNormalResId`. And this is how I use it in my `onCreate` of Not-MainActivity:

```
fabMenu.setMenuButtonColorNormalResId(MainActivity.fabColor);
```

fabColor is `public static int`, Im getting it from Shared preferences like this:

```
fabColor = mSharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_FAB_COLOR, R.color.colorAccent);
```

which I set in my ThemeActivity

Answer (score 0):

You should save your colours in `resources` `res/values/colors.xml` file and the get them anywhere in the project by calling `getResources().getColor(colorInt)`. More information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color 
It is not a good practice to save colors in SharedPreferences in Android.

Comment: Sorry but your answer has nothing to do with question. I know everything you wrote, and yes, Im keeping my colors in res/values/colors, but in my app user can change colors and that color value needs to be stored in SharedPrefs for next time users starts the app.

Comment: Then I still would not store integer colour values in SharedPreferences. I would store colour key as a `String` there. Then in the method which needs to set the colour I would map this key to the corresponding colour from the colors.xml

Comment: I'm not storing integer color values, its integer color resource id! And using `String` and then using `int` corresponding to that `String` is one unnecessary step. Method `.setMenuButtonColorNormalResId` needs an `int`, and... The question here isn't about storing colors to SP, its about `Resources$NotFoundException` that occur in some cases and why?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work the resource Ids are generated and can change.. that's why it is better idea not to rely on them and not to store them in SP ;)