# Are resources lazy loaded?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-resources

I have read the *awesome* answer on the internals of Android resources by @hackbod :
[How does the mapping between android resources and resources ID work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517151/how-does-the-mapping-between-android-resources-and-resources-id-work)

Here is the brief version: The resources, as you may probably know are compiled to a binary format as `resources.arsc` and are available through the `Resources` class. These resources are compiled such that they can be easily m-mapped(or mapped to memory).

Now, my question is that are these resources loaded all at once in the memory(presumably during Application process creation) or they are loaded lazily as and when they are required?

Comment: AFAIK, they are loaded lazily, but are cached and retained once they are loaded.

Comment: @CommonsWare I saw that there is a file ApkAssets, that is immutable in memory representation of your APK. That is built once and shared.

Can we say that, strings.xml is loaded when that apk-assets object is created, and probably that happens when the first resource whether image, bitmap, font or anything is loaded.

Comment: @vishal_ratna: I do not know -- sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the code is the resources are eagerly loaded at the time of reading the APK file.
There is a file called `PackageParser` that has a method `parseBaseApk`.
You will observe that while loading the package these things happen, the above method[`parseBaseApk`] accepts `assets` as an argument. That comes from an `AssetManager` that in turn comes from an `AssetLoader`.

Internally android APK assets, are represented as an `AssetAPK` array. Each array item could be in-memory representation of asset type `FORMAT_ARSC`, `FORMAT_IDMAP`, `FORMAT_DIR`.
Inside `APKAssets` there is a `StringBlock`, that represents the compiled string/font resources, and this is created at the time of creation of `ApkAssets`.

So, I believe the resources are eagerly loaded at the time of loading and parsing the APK, unless I am missing some details out.