# R.id.X values are wrong during debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging

[image]

If I do this in code: `val x = R.id.x` - it will have value like `32123123412`.

If I evaluate expression/add to variables watcher this during debug: `R.id.x` - it will have value like `-123456` and `x == R.id.x` - will be `false`.
It also means that `findViewById<View>(R.id.x)` will found nothing, while `findViewById<View>(x)` - will work just fine during debugging.

For some reason all `R` values during debug differ from values in code. I found file `R.txt` in build and it had `32123123412` for `R.id.x`. But I found no files with `-123456`.

Where does `-123456` comes from? How can I make `R.id.x` same in code and during debug? This is extremely bad during espresso tests debugging.

**UPD:** problem occurs only in kotlin files. If I create java file and call it from kotlin and check ids there - it will work fine

**UPD2:** `android.R.id.content` works fine even in kotlin

**UPD3:** if in evaluate expression menu choose `java` and try to see `R.id.X` - `R` - will be unresolved reference, even if package fully specified

**UPD4:** opened task in kotlin bugtracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42479

Comment: please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/12225996

Comment: Resource identifiers are NOT STABLE, they are reassigned during each build. You should never keep hard reference to their absolute value, only refer to them using their identifier.

Comment: I'm using references, not absolute values. I updated question with `It also means that findViewById<View>(R.id.x) will found nothing, while findViewById<View>(x) - will work just fine.`

Comment: @Ehsanmsz but that means the problem is even more confusing since `1903226` translates to `1D0A7A` which does not map to PPTTNNNN pattern, if we compare it to the correct value `2131956990` which is `7F1314FE`. Later is from `app`, first if from `library` it seems. Later TT is `13` vs `1D` from first. NNNN is also completely different

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a bug with kotlin. Developers acknowledged the issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42479