# AAPT2 warning about "Unknown chunk type"

Tags: android, aapt2

I'm building an Android app targeting Android API 33 (Android 13). When I build the app on the command line using gradlew, I see the following warning:

```
aapt2 W 09-02 02:57:09  6715  6715 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
```

What on earth does this mean, and should I expect side effects?

Comment: I got these when using RoboElectric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take a look at the `LoadedAsrc.cpp` file mentioned, used in relation to [resources.arsc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6646113/608312). Your warning mentions line 682, and if we look a few lines before that, we can [see your warning on line 677](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/androidfw/LoadedArsc.cpp#677).

This warning seems to happen if whilst looking through the "overlayable policy chunks", we find a `overlayable_child_chunk.type()` that does *not* equal `RES_TABLE_OVERLAYABLE_POLICY_TYPE`.

By looking at the `switch` and `case` statements, we can see that child chunks of a `RES_TABLE_TYPE_SPEC_TYPE` chunk should be of type `RES_TABLE_OVERLAYABLE_POLICY_TYPE`, defined [in this older copy of the code](https://github.com/facebook/redex/blob/main/libresource/androidfw/ResourceTypes.h#L106) as `0x0205` (517?), not the `200` shown in your error. When a child chunk is the incorrect type, we go to `default`, throwing the warning seen.

This warning is being called inside `LoadedPackage::Load`, where we are trying to populate `type_builder_map` using `loaded_package` (see line 748). So, now we know that we're seeing this warning because a child chunk type is set incorrectly whilst trying to do... something around building up a map of types. This is summarised as:

```
  // A map of TypeSpec builders, each associated with an type index.
  // We use these to accumulate the set of Types available for a TypeSpec, and later build a single,
  // contiguous block of memory that holds all the Types together with the TypeSpec.
```

At this point, there's not much value in diving deeper in my opinion. The main takeaway is:

**This warning is generated deep inside the compiler, and doesn't matter so long as everything works. It is caused by a type mismatch whilst building up a mapping for your app's `resources.arsc` file.**

**I strongly suspect it's just a compiler bug, and doubt you can fix it yourself besides waiting for a later compiler version (updating target API) where this will hopefully be fixed.**

However, if you do want to dive deeper, I found [this Chinese analysis](https://blog.csdn.net/lijie2664989/article/details/111404425) (needs translating, search in page for `LoadedPackage::Load`!) extremely detailed. It contains a high level description of the `load` function, the file itself, and what the chunk loading actually means.

It includes this helpful diagram, showing how all the parts interact, and specifically our `_TYPE` parsing:

[image: apk assets parsing]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to decrease you target API to 30 or 31? Due to it being the latest version, I suppose that the build tools are unable to build the app. You can try API 30 or 31

Comment: The app appears to build OK for API 33. My question is more about what the warning means, and whether there are any side effects.

Comment: Its a warning and not an error which makes me believe that there should be no side effects.

Comment: it's only a warning until it's not "AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit". What it is that actually causes this error to appear? it is a bug of some sort but why does it happen when upgrading old projects, what is the actual resource type etc..